# Cannot check login error (blank)

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have problem with login validation. The problem is when i try to login using admin, the page stop on checklogin.php and won't tell if it is succeed or not. Here is my code.

Index.html

```
    <body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Aplikasi Pengelola Data Pelatihan dan Seminar</h1>
      <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <p><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="login-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

checklogin.php

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
   if(isset($_POST['username']))
   {
       $username=$_POST['username'];
   }
   if(isset($_POST['password']))
   {
       $password=$_POST['password'];
   }

   // Connect to database.
   $host="localhost"; // Host name.
   $db_user="root"; // MySQL username.
   $db_password=""; // MySQL password.
   $db="seminardanpelatihan"; // Database.
   $con = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db);
   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
       echo "Failed to connect : " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   else
   {
        mysqli_select_db($con, $db);
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['username']= "username";
            $_SESSION['password']= "password";
            header("login_success.php"); // Re-direct to login_success.php
        }
         else
        { 
            echo "Something wrong";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
   }
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have to start session at top of your page??

Comment: Answer submitted by @uzumaki is what this question is if this does not work please show us the mysql table or post any errors if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change the first line of your code:

```
   <?php
if (isset($_POST['login']))
```

to

```
   <?php
if (isset($_POST['username']))
```

this will give you the option to execute all the code of the page if the user will post at least the username. I'd prefer to go for something even more strict:

```
   <?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])
```

so you won't run the code if the user doesn't submit both the values. (only username or only password will anyway fail the validation!)

Then: your issue is that you don't retrieve the values from the query.

```
mysqli_select_db($con, $db);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
```

is ok to check if you have one and only one result but then you have to add after those lines:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$username = $row['username'];
$password = $row['password'];
session_start();
```

and then edit the following two this way:

```
$_SESSION['username']= $username;
$_SESSION['password']= $password;
```

Also note that I wouldn't store the password in `$_SESSION` array or in any other value in my code and that I'd suggest you to use some encryption method on the password.

Comment: You should always write `mysqi_fetch_array()` method in `while` loop. I know this works but Its a good practise to write !!! cheers

Comment: No, you don't need since this code is executed after an if statement that check if there is only one row. Do not put any extra line of code if it is not necessary. This is a very simple code but when it comes to bigger codes performance can be important.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['commit']))
```

I tested.
**Edit**
Also Change (Dont skip previous changes)

```
      $_SESSION['username']= "username";
      $_SESSION['password']= "password";                
      header("login_success.php");
```

To

```
      $_SESSION['username']= $username;
      $_SESSION['password']= $password;
      header("Location: login_success.php"); //Proper Redirect Method
```

1)You need `Location:` prefix for redirect
2)You used `"username"` instead of `$username`

Comment: 've tried to change it but still stuck in checklogin.php.

Comment: @TeddyMapandin, Try these new changes too

Comment: thank you, but still error on line 26 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
 . I don't understand which variable that undefined..?

Comment: @TeddyMapandin, I just created a database and tested it, it worked fine for me. I think you are missig username, or password column in your table, or table with name login itself.